# Why is text in PowerPoint messed up?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

When I open a PowerPoint presentation, the text is messed up.

Screenshot:

[image]

This happens even if I create a new file. What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

I'm using Microsoft PowerPoint 2007, the font is Calibri (Body).

Comment: Try changing your default printer to standard XPS printer

Comment: Wow first strike.... It works... Thanks @MartheenCahyaPaulo. You should post from Answer side....

Comment: Yea, happened to my coworker last week. The weirdest problem & solution ever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the default printer to other printer (either the standard XPS printer or any other). This is because for inexplicable reason, PowerPoint (the only non-print oriented Office app) utilize something from the default printer driver info for rendering the font. On old printer (think dot-matrix old) it's incompatible with the newer PowerPoint.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and then this question **SOLVED**